# sqllite database location for codename one

Tags: codenameone

SQL lite created by using the following code

```
   Database db = Database.openOrCreate("test.db");
```

Its creates the database, after that we created tables on this database. We need to know where is this test.db file stored?.

Note: we are using Net Beans IDE on windows 10 system for our development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the [SQL section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql). You need to use `getDatabasePath` **before** opening the database to replace the file with a premade file which I assume is the use case you are aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the .db file from the path "C:\Users\Admin.cn1\database".